# Disable whitespace-mode for single mode

Tags: whitespace-mode

I'm using `global-whitespace-mode` with a particular `whitespace-style` as a default for all modes. How can I disable `whitespace-mode` *completely* for a single mode, eg. incoming email?

I tried the following, but I still get all the default whitespace styles when looking at incoming email.

```el
(global-whitespace-mode)
(setq whitespace-style '(face trailing lines tabs big-indent))
(add-hook 'rmail-mode-hook '(whitespace-mode 0))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6837511 might also prove informative.

Comment: @phils: Very interesting! How do I enable this? `(setq whitespace-global-modes '(prog-mode))` did't work.

Comment: It's not using `derived-mode-p` so you can't use `prog-mode` here (unless you are actually editing a buffer with major mode `prog-mode`, which in practice you wouldn't ever do).  You have to list individual major modes. But *surely* (based on your question) you want to use the syntax shown in that duplicate: `'(not rmail-mode)`

Comment: I see. Then, I agree!

Answer (score 3):

You can do like that:

```el
(define-global-minor-mode my-global-whitespace-mode whitespace-mode
  (lambda ()
    (unless (derived-mode-p 'rmail-mode 'term-mode)
      (whitespace-mode))))
(my-global-whitespace-mode 1)
```

Or activate only for prog-mode

```el
(define-global-minor-mode my-global-whitespace-mode whitespace-mode
  (lambda ()
    (when (derived-mode-p 'prog-mode)
      (whitespace-mode))))
(my-global-whitespace-mode 1)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm highlighting not just trailing whitespace, but several other types of whitespace as well. `show-trailing-whitespace` onlys affect trailing whitespace at the end of lines, doesn't it? Whereas I wish to get rid of *all* whitespace highlighting for incoming email. Updated my original post. Sorry about that. How does that affect your suggestion?

Comment: So you can use the first proposition.

Comment: You have to define a new mode to disable whitespace-mode for particular modes? It's not possible with a one-liner?

Comment: Yes, I don't think so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837511/automatically-disable-a-global-minor-mode-for-a-specific-major-mode

Comment: I want whitespace-mode where it makes sense, i.e.. all programming languages and shell scripts, and off for everything else (email, dired, plain text, etc.) Can Emacs distinguish "code modes" from all else so this can be automated?

Comment: with prog-mode. See edit